# Is there a way to get an application's path to add it to the registry automatically and run alongside Windows startup in C++?

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm developing an application and would like to know if there's a way to get it's executable path automatically and run alongside Windows startup by adding it to the registry.

This is my function so far:

```
void Open(){


HKEY hKey;

WCHAR path[MAX_PATH]; //to store the directory

DWORD size = GetModuleFileNameW(NULL, path, MAX_PATH);



const char* StartName = "MyApplication";


LONG lnRes = RegOpenKeyEx(  HKEY_CURRENT_USER,
                            "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run",
                            0 , KEY_WRITE,
                            &hKey);
if( ERROR_SUCCESS == lnRes )
{
    lnRes = RegSetValueEx(  hKey,
                            StartName,
                            0,
                            REG_SZ,
                            (LPBYTE)path,
                            size );
}

RegCloseKey(hKey);
}
```

I'm using GetModuleFileName to get the path, but it returns me the path with a single backslash and in the registry it only recognizes the "D" drive. For example: D:\Usuario\Desktop\log\mariobros.exe

https://prnt.sc/vondsi (Here's a print from my registry)

I suspect that the problem is that for the code to be recognized as a single backslash it needs to have a double backslash. This is how I think it should've need to be: D:\\Usuario\\Desktop\\log\\mariobros.exe

Does anyone know what could I do here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Double-backslashes are only needed for literals or cases where a second layer of interpretation is being applied (e.g. regular expressions). You don't need it for paths acquired programmatically. You don't need extra backslashes.

Comment: Oh, I see. But why would only my D drive be recognized in the registry?

Comment: Is your program being compiled in `_UNICODE`/`UNICODE` mode or not? You use explicit `W` suffixed methods in some places, but if you're not compiling in `UNICODE` mode, the unprefixed methods will be implicitly the `A` suffixed versions, and you'll be passing `wchar`s to functions expecting `char` and vice-versa (e.g. `RegSetValueEx` is receiving a wide char `path`, so `RegSetValueExA` would have issues; `RegOpenKeyEx` is receiving a narrow char registry path, so `RegOpenKeyExW` would have issues). I'd suggest being consistent; always use `W` APIs, always use `L`-prefixed string literals.

Comment: I think it is in UNICODE, but i get what you're saying. Changed the path to CHAR and GetModuleFileNameW to just GetModuleFileName and it worked. Thank you so much!

Comment: That implies your compilation settings are non-Unicode. You're defaulting to `A` suffixed APIs.

Comment: Oh, got it. Thanks

Comment: because string from this key used as [*commandline*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/setupapi/run-and-runonce-registry-keys) for [*CreateProcessW*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw) - *If you are using a long file name that contains a space, use quoted strings to indicate where the file name ends and the arguments begin* - because you dont know are will be space in returned path always insert " in begin and end of path. for example - https://pastebin.com/14uhmmiu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are clearly compiling with `UNICODE` *undefined* in your project, which means `RegOpenKeyEx()` and `RegSetValueEx()` are actually calling the ANSI functions `RegOpenKeyExA()` and `RegSetValueExA()`, respectively (as evident by you being able to pass `char*` strings to them without compiler errors).

But, you are retrieving the file path as a Unicode UTF-16 string and passing it as-is to `RegSetValueExA()`, so you end up with embedded `nul` characters written to the Registry when `RegSetValueExA()` *misinterprets* your UTF-16 string as an ANSI string and *re-encodes* each of its bytes individually to Unicode characters.  Unicode characters in the ASCII range have `nul` bytes in them.

Since you are using a Unicode function to retrieve the file path, and because the Registry internally stores strings in Unicode form only, you should use the Registry's Unicode functions to match that same encoding.

Also, note that the return value of `GetModuleFileName(A|W)` *does not* include the null terminator in the output string's length, but `RegSetValueEx(A|W)` expects the `cbSize` parameter to include enough bytes for a null terminator for `REG_(EXPAND_|MULTI_)SZ` value types.

Try this:

```cpp
void Open()
{
    WCHAR path[MAX_PATH]; //to store the directory

    DWORD size = GetModuleFileNameW(NULL, path, MAX_PATH);
    if ((size > 0) && (size < MAX_PATH))
    {
        HKEY hKey;
        LONG lnRes = RegOpenKeyExW(HKEY_CURRENT_USER,
                                L"SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run",
                                0, KEY_SET_VALUE,
                                &hKey);
        if( ERROR_SUCCESS == lnRes )
        {
            lnRes = RegSetValueExW(hKey,
                                    L"MyApplication",
                                    0,
                                    REG_SZ,
                                    (LPBYTE)path,
                                    (size + 1) * sizeof(WCHAR) );

            RegCloseKey(hKey);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: also because string from this key used as [*commandline*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/setupapi/run-and-runonce-registry-keys) for [*CreateProcessW*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw) -*If you are using a long file name that contains a space, use quoted strings to indicate where the file name ends and the arguments begin* - so need always insert " " in begin and end of path returned by `GetModuleFileNameW`

Answer (score 0):

This looks like you are passing a wide string, while promising that it is a narrow string (evident by your C-style cast).

The second byte in a wide string is 0, and this terminates your narrow string.

Suggestion: use wide strings only while dealing with Win API.

Comment: The cast is needed whether the API is `RegSetValueExA` or `RegSetValueExW` (they both take `const BYTE*` as the argument); the OP would need to reveal their compilation settings for us to know whether `RegSetValueEx` is the former or the latter.

Comment: @ShadowRanger we already know implicitly what the compilation setting is set to, by virtue of the fact that `RegOpenKeyEx()` and `RegSetValueEx()` are accepting `char*` strings without error, which means the compilation must clearly be set with `UNICODE` **disabled**.